# Stuck in broken i3 wm and don't know how to get it back to xfce

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, i3

So, i installed i3 with the wrong commands on my mint 19.2 with xfce4 and got a broken version and since my system is set for "open without the account screen" its stuck there, i3 only showed me some error at status and nothing else, fixed it with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install i3-wm i3status i3lock suckless-tools` now i have the working status at bottom but nothing else, i cant use any key or can't write anything, my best bet is the alt+ctrl+f4 commandline, is there a way to get out of this or did i blow another virtual machine up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default i3 key bindings should be active. To go back to xfce, exit i3 with the keyboard combination ALT+SHIFT+E

That should log you out and take you to your display manager. From there you can select xfce and log in.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you get to a running i3 session, which has nothing but the status bar. i3 uses a mod-key to do most things. On my computers, it has been the Windows key. If you hold the Windows key and press enter, you should get a shell. If you don't have a Windows key or it doesn't work, try Alt or Ctrl.

In that shell, perhaps you can use a package manager (aptitude?) to remove i3 and get xfce back?